# Bluetooth does not work in 16.04

Tags: bluetooth

After installing 16.04.2 LTS just this week I find a few small but somewhat annoying issues, such as no blue tooth.

After searching and trying several different fixes I am left with the same situation of this item unresolved. It only led to installing a clean OS again so I now sit and wait.

How or what should do to fix these items or just wait for programmer to come up with the answer?

```
Lenovo-Yoga-2-Pro Kernel: 4.8.0-52-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: Unity 7.4.0 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3)
           Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: LENOVO product: 20266 v: Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro
           Mobo: LENOVO model: Yoga2 v: 31900056WIN
           Bios: LENOVO v: 76CN43WW date: 03/30/2015
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-4510U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 4096 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 10375
           clock speeds: max: 3100 MHz 1: 2295 MHz 2: 2000 MHz 3: 2540 MHz
           4: 2432 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
           bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 3200x1800@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 8 Series HD Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Card-2 Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.8.0-52-generic
Network:   Card: Intel Wireless 7260 driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 01:00.0
           IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 512.1GB (10.0% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: SAMSUNG_MZMTE512 size: 512.1GB temp: 0C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 235G used: 41G (18%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 8.50GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda6
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 56.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 226 Uptime: 54 min Memory: 1725.0/7895.1MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Comment: It depends how the bug was reported. A fire-and-forget complaint in a random forum will be unread, unfixed, and there will be no feedback. A proper bug report at launchpad.net will include the fix and feedback as part of the report file. If you are interested in reporting bugs, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Is it 14.04.2 or 16.04.2?

Comment: @Pilot6 my system is 16.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my bluetooth problems by [following this tutorial](https://github.com/dlech/ev3dev.github.io/blob/58f60076ed66f58d4e068c039d30f7546b7e7a0b/docs/tutorials/connecting-to-the-internet-via-bluetooth.md). I had to install `blueman` in Ubuntu. It can be done by running the command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

After that, run the Blueman Bluetooth Manager and bluetooth will work.